# Using pointers to perform the action of "strcat()"

Tags: c, string, pointers, gcc

I used pointers to perform the action of `strcat()`.

**Practice.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char src[]="Hello";
  char tgt[]="Ladies";

  xstrcat(src,tgt);                                      // LINE 1.
  printf("\nTGT[] = %s\nSRC[] = %s",tgt,src);

  return 0;
}


xstrcat(char *t, const char *s)
{
  while(*t!='\0')
    ++t;

  while(*s!='\0')
  {
    *t=*s;
    ++t;++s;
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
TGT[] = Ladies
SRC[] = HelloLadies
```

Now as soon as I replaced `xstrcat(src,tgt);` with `xstrcat(tgt,src)` check `LINE 1.`, the output of the program changes as well.

**NEW OUTPUT**

```
TGT[] = LadiesHelloo
SRC[] = elloo
```

As u can clearly see that the output is not as desired. `o` is repeated and `H` is trimmed.

I doubted my `xstrcat(char *t, char *s)` function first. So I used default `strcat()` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char src[]="There";
  char tgt[]="Go";

  strcat(src,tgt);                           //LINE 2
  printf("\nTGT[] = %s\nSRC = %s",tgt,src);
}
```

**OUTPUT As expected**

```
TGT[] = Go
SRC[] = ThereGo
```

Now, when I replaced `strcat(src,tgt)` with `srtcat(tgt,src)` in `LINE 2`, the following is the output:

```
TGT[] = GoThere
SRC[] = here
```

U see, `T` from `src[]` is trimmed in the output.

***Question:*** Why is the reason for all this behavior?

Comment: You´ve not enough memory in tgt => undefined behaviour.

Comment: 'strcat' and functions doing the same needs a space in the buffer where they copy. In your case there is no space and you have buffer overrun (you concatenate to `src` but `src` has space for `"There"` only).

Comment: Try: `char src[100] = "hello", tgt[100] = "Ladies";`

Comment: Two problems: First the [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) mentioned, then that the arguments for `xstrcpy` are named `t` and `s` (for "target" and "source" I presume) in that order, but you call it with `src` and `tgt` in that order, which seems to indicate that source is the first argument, opposite of the actual function.

Comment: @deviantfan Well that solves the second part using the `strcat(tgt,src)`. But what about the first part, where I have used pointers. Is this the reason for them too?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg U assumed correct. But does it really affects, switching the `tgt` with `src` & vice-versa in `xstrcat()` in `main` function.

Comment: @VSP: Um, yes? The order of parameters isn´t just for fun.

Comment: @WilliamPursell It worked. But can u please elaborate it a bit, like how it actually happened?

Comment: @VSP: How about a C book?

Comment: @VSP Size matters.  `char src[]="Hello"` creates an array of size 6, while `char src[100]` creates an array of size 100.  Use `sizeof src` to see the difference.

Comment: I think you also forget to null terminate your string at the end of function `xstrcat`